# .htaccess - Too many redirects on mobile devices (iOS, android)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, mobile

I'am trying to understand for a while now, why my rewrite rules in .htaccess file give me an error. It happens only on mobile devices (iOS and android), works fine on desktop browsers. The error is too many redirects. I'm trying to 301 redirect http traffic to https. Here is my code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(.*/)?\.(git|svn|hg|bzr)+ - [R=404,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried running it through a tester like this one http://htaccess.mwl.be/

Comment: @P. Galbraith the tester you sent me didn't work for me because: There are a couple of things which are not supported yet (like %{REQUEST_FILENAME}) but we hope to add them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on$ [OR]` to `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]`

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't change anything :(

Comment: The rewrite rules look fine. I am assuming you have the closing `</IfModule>`. Are you sure your application isn't doing some sort of mobile redirect to the `http` url?

Comment: Yes, the closing tag is there. And yes, there is a router in the application and probably it is causing problems. At the moment I made a 301 redirect in PHP, which is working fine, but not the solution I prefer in a long time... I'll try to dig in to this router and hopefully fix it. Thnx for help.